# outerClass.get()?.tv_receive?とは何か

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Kotlinでネットワーク関連のコードを書いており、以下のページを参考にしました。
https://medium.com/@hongminlai/android-kotlin-udp-socket-fba4474ea0b1

```
class UDPSocketActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var udpSocket: UdpSocket? = null
    private var handler: Handler
    init {
        val outerClass = WeakReference(this)
        handler = MyHandler(outerClass)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        udpSocket = UdpSocket(handler)
        udpSocket?.startUDPSocket()

        button.setOnClickListener {
            udpSocket?.sendMessage(editText.text.toString())
        }

    }

    // Declare the Handler as a static class.
    class MyHandler(private val outerClass: WeakReference<MainActivity>) : Handler() {

        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
            outerClass.get()?.tv_receive?.append(msg?.obj.toString()+"\n")
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        udpSocket?.stopUDPSocket()
    }
}
```

`outerClass.get()?.tv_receive?`という行があり、そこがエラーになります。
`tv_receive`とは何なのでしょうか？
何かのライブラリ等をimportしたらエラーが消えるものなのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

過去利用されていた [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://developers-jp.googleblog.com/2020/11/the-future-of-kotlin-android-extensions.html) の synthetics という機能かと思います。

Qiita に解説を書かれている方がいらっしゃいます:

- [もうちょっと詳しくなるKotlin Android ExtensionsでのView Binding](https://qiita.com/kafumi/items/391dafe997064da2bb6c)

`tv_recieve` という名前から推測すると、受信データ表示用の `TextView` を `UDPSocketActivity` に備えているのかと思います。